# replace string in multiple Pandas columns

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I was wondering how to replace specific values in multiple columns in Pandas. For example, if I want to replace certain value in 1 column I would use:

```py
df['column_1']=df['column_1'].str.replace(':',' '')
```

but I don't know an easy way to do the same thing if I have say 5 columns.

Comment: Checkout pandas `apply` method. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: You can use `pandas.DataFrame.replace`, which is designed for your use.

Comment: Like stated by @Chris you can use `replace`. It would look like `df [['a', 'b']]= df [['a', 'b']].replace(':', '')` if you want to apply that for columns a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have column names like *column_1*, *column_2*, ...
*column_5* and you want to apply your function to columns e.g. from
*column_1* to *column_4*, you can run:

```
df.loc[:, 'column_1':'column_4'] = df.loc[:, 'column_1':'column_4']\
    .apply(lambda src: src.replace(':', ''))
```